# Number of Significant Digits of HTML Numeric Reference Characters

Tags: html, browser, unicode, utf-8, utf-32

What are the specifications for the number of digits in the numeric reference character (decimal) in HTML?

For example, `&#037;` represents a `%`.
Likewise, `&#0000037;` represents a `%`.
How many zeros can be placed between &# and 37?

I searched the text of the HTML Living Standard. I found a description of the numeric reference character, but no description of the number of digits.

Comment: https://hakre.wordpress.com/2010/02/25/html-entity-boundaries-zero-padding/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. [Do some research](https://www.google.com/search?q=html+numerical+entity+padding), if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)